# google OAuth consent screen - "something went wrong"

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-signin

I am writing an app with flutter that needs Google Calendar permission from the user.

I setup my consent screen in the Google Cloud Console with the correct scopes and added myself as a test user, but when I try to login in the app the consent screen shows an error [image: something went wrong]

This is how my consent screen is set up:
[image: conesnt screen]

This is how I initialize my GoogleSignIn object:

```
_googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: [
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.app.created',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.calendarlist'
        ])
```

The scopes match those in the consent screen.

If it is any clue, my Google Cloud console shows the errors in the `Identity Toolkit Api`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous answer of [spaceMonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65821740/google-api-oauth-2-sign-in-something-went-wrong-with-new-oauth-2-client) to a similar question, it seems that when the OAuth flow is initiated that requires the user to sign to their Google account, the flow works.

When the user uses test accounts, that's when the generic error shows. As a workaround, they use accounts that are authenticated and can sign-in to their Google account.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am using my own google account, so I am going through the account picker. I am using restricted access scopes, and don't have all the things needed to submit my app for approval, but it seems that using my google account as a test user uis bugged